# How to Use Session Like C# page to VB Page Using Page Methods

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

after run two or more times it will give the value like Empty "" or nothing..
How to Do?
My 1st Page aa.aspx i did 
**In javascript**

```
function InitializeRequest(path) {
// call server side method
PageMethods.SetDownloadPath(path);
}
```

**Code behind**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SetDownloadPath(string strpath)
{
Page objp = new Page();
objp.Session["strDwnPath"] = strpath; 
return strpath;
}
```

**aspx Page**

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" ID="MainSM" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
```

how i can get strpath value into bb.aspx  vb code behind???

Comment: Do not need to create `Page` object for use `Session` in  `WebMethod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SetDownloadPath(string strpath)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Session["strDwnPath"] = strpath;
        return strpath;
}
```

Comment: how to get that value in vb Web page?

Comment: i used  `Dim SysNames = Session("strDwnPath").ToString()`  in bb.aspx  Page load but it will give one error like **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: @Suresh - `upvote` the answer will helps other to find correct solutions. Glad to help you :)

Comment: Its not working.. if i run 1st time means it will give correct answer otherwise it will come error and session("strDwnPath") value is nothing? wat i can do?

Comment: you should check somewhere in you page load or other events.may be you are assign `null` to you `session "strDwnPath"  in your other events.

Comment: No Prog ,, I checked But it will Come Error,,, How i can Get the Session value in another web page?

Comment: simply : `string deom = Convert.ToString(Session["strDwnPath"]);` in C#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64620/discussion-between-suresh-and-prog).